# How to save text file to orc in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to spark, I am trying to save my text file to orc using spark-shell is their any way to do that?

```
vall data =sc.textFile("/yyy/yyy/yyy")
data.saveAsOrcFile("/yyy/yyy/yyy")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the RDD to DataFrame and then save it.

```
data.toDF().write.format("orc").save("/path/to/save/file")
```

To read it back, use sqlContext

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)

val data = sqlContext.read.format("orc").load("/path/to/file/*")
```